# Foreign key is always 0 in relation one to one

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, database-design

In relation 1 - 1, I have two foreign keys in each of tabels that should tell me to what object I', referring. In table "WebAppUser" foreign key works correctly but in table "UserPermissions" I always get 0 as id of foreign key (column: "WebAppUserId" which is reference to a specific "WebAppUser").

My Code:

```
public class UserPermissions
{
    [Key]
    public int UserPermissionsId { get; set; }
    //public int? WebAppUserId { get; set; }
    public int WebAppUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual WebAppUser WebAppUser { get; set; }
    /*public virtual IEnumerable<WebAppUserClaims> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<WebAppUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<WebAppUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }*/
    public virtual IEnumerable<WebAppUserRole> WebAppUserRoles { get; set; }
}



public class WebAppUser /*: IdentityUser<int>*/
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //1:1
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    //1:1
    public int UserCredentialsId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCredential Credentials { get; set; }
    //1:1
    public int PermissionsId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserPermissions UserPermissions { get; set; }
}



//WebAppUser - UserPermissions 1-1
modelBuilder.Entity<WebAppUser>()
.HasOne(x => x.UserPermissions)
.WithOne(y => y.WebAppUser)
.HasForeignKey<WebAppUser>(x => x.PermissionsId);
```

[image: WebAppUser table view:]

[image: UserPermissions table view]

I tried entity configuration like this, but it also doesn't work:

````
            modelBuilder.Entity<WebAppUser>()
           .HasOne(x => x.UserPermissions)
           .WithOne(y => y.WebAppUser)
           .HasForeignKey<WebAppUser>(x => x.PermissionsId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserPermissions>()
            .HasOne(x => x.WebAppUser)
            .WithOne(y => y.UserPermissions)
            .HasForeignKey<UserPermissions>(x => x.WebAppUserId);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in fluentApi

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WebAppUser>()
.HasOne<UserPermissions>(x => x.UserPermissions)
.WithOne(y => y.WebAppUser)
.HasForeignKey<UserPermissions>(x => x.WebAppUserId);
```

And don't forget when you make a request to this table to use Include(x => x.UserPermissions)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately now I get PermissionId = 0 in WebAppUser table, but  in table UserPermissions everything works fine.

Comment: Yes PermissionId can stay zero , but if you make query like ```context.WebAppUsers.Include(x => x.UserPermissions).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)``` Your ```WebAppUser.UserPermissions``` will be loaded. So now you have ```WebAppUser.UserPermissions.Id``` and all data in ```UserPermissions``` you need

Comment: Ok, I get it, but is there possibility to add foreign key to table? For example to check whos user permissions I browsing?

Comment: You want to check it by  WebAppUserId ?

Comment: You have the foreign key, just use the inner model not the ModelId

Comment: Like ```context.Permissions.Include(x => x.WebAppUser).FirstOrDefault(x => x.WebAppUser.Id == userId)``` now you have the permission with WebAppUser data in it

Comment: I meant on table level, I want to have table UserPermissions where WebAppUserId will be automatically generated when adding entity to database :)

Comment: If you mean in to the database table you can make join and get same date as in code